# PHP Slim framework generates CSRF Token on each connection

Tags: php, angularjs, csrf, slim

Currently I am trying to build a website with slim as backend and angularJS as fronend. Therefore I took a look at several tutorials and demo projects. This was the most interesting one: https://github.com/alexdebril/slim-angular

Out of the box I have a problem with the CSRF implementation. In this project the CSRF protection is implemented in the middleware, in order to apply on every connection. Good or not is irrelevant.
But when I install all the dependencies with composer and npm, the project is not working well because every server connection gets a new CSRF token that will be stored in the PHP Session.

So on the main page of this project there is a angular form that will send a string secured with the csrf token to the server. The server then only replies with thw same string and the angular controller prints it out. WHen I trigger the form submit the first time, everything will be fine, but on the second submit, the server will respond with a error 400 because he has a new csrf token that angular does not have yet.

But the creator of this example project could not have made such an error, could he? Why does my apache creates a new csrf token for each connection with the same user? and how can I solve this problem?

My dependencies:
slim\slim v3.8.1
slim\csrf v0.7.0
angular v1.6.4 (route, aria, material, ui-bootstrap, cookie, http-auth-interceptor)

So how can I have only one CSRF token for each user?
Or how do I have to update the tokenizer service in angular in order to use always the newest CSRF token? Or do I need a watcher? to detect this?

Comment: The documentation for slim-angular explains how to tokenize each request. See [slim-angular Tokenizer Example](https://github.com/alexdebril/slim-angular#tokenizer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed Slim's own CSRF Package (slim/csrf) because there are several problems with this in addition to angular.
Instead I now use XSRF Tokens that will be transmitted in the header. Angular can handle this just fine and completely out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear they're using [`slim-csrf`](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Csrf), which fortunately has a setting to disable regenerating the CSRF token on every request. According to the [GitHub readme](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Csrf#token-persistence):

> By default, `Slim\Csrf\Guard` will generate a fresh name/value pair after each request.  This is an important security measure for [certain situations](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2013/02/preventing-csrf-attacks.html).  However, in many cases this is unnecessary, and [a single token throughout the user's session will suffice](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Synchronizer_.28CSRF.29_Tokens).  By using per-session requests it becomes easier, for example, to process AJAX requests without having to retrieve a new CSRF token (by reloading the page or making a separate request) after each request.

So, in `/php/middleware.php`, just set the 6th parameter to `true`, and leave the rest as `null`. For a list of what the other 5 options do, you can just take a look at the [source](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Csrf/blob/master/src/Guard.php#L78-L95).

Comment: I already tried this. But then `$name = $request->getAttribute($container->csrf->getTokenNameKey());$value = $request->getAttribute($container->csrf->getTokenValueKey());` does not output any CSRF key (only `null`).  Also there is still the problem, that, if the server generates a new token because of a wrong connection, angular does not detect it. So the main question should be: How can I detect a CSRF token change in angular? (then it does not matter if there would be a new token each connection or maybe only a new token on an attack or wrong auth.)